# Which to use - "operator new" or "operator new[]" - to allocate a block of raw memory in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-management

My C++ program needs a block of uninitialized memory and a `void*` pointer to that block so that I can give it to a third party library. I want to pass control of the block lifetime to the library, so I don't want to use `std::vector`. When the library is done with the block it will call a callback that I have to supply and that will deallocate the block. In C I would use `malloc()` and later `free()`.

In C++ I can either call `::operator new` or `::operator new[]` and `::operator delete` or `operator delete[]` respectively later:

```
void* newBlock = ::operator new( sizeOfBlock );
// then, later
::operator delete( newBlock );
```

Looks like both `::operator new` and `::operator new[]` have exactly the same signature and exactly the same behavior. The same for `::operator delete` and `::operator delete[]`. The only thing I shouldn't do is pairing `operator new` with `operator delete[]` and vice versa - undefined behavior. Other than that which pair do I choose and why?

Comment: I assume you know you should use `std::vector<char>`, yadda yadda.

Comment: Why do you think that with std::vector you do not have control over the lifetime of the object?

Comment: The question is unclear.  Do you have control over deallocation, or do you pass that responsibility to a library?  All of the answers from before that edit don't address the modified requirements.

Comment: @Roger Pate: Clarified about deallocation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `new` with a single object and `new[]` with an array of objects. So, for example:

```
int* x = new int; // Allocates single int
int* y = new int[5]; // Allocates an array of integers

*x = 10; // Assignment to single value
y[0] = 8; // Assignment to element of the array
```

If all you are doing is allocating a memory buffer, then allocate an array of `char` as in:

```
int bufferlen = /* choose a buffer size somehow */
char* buffer = new char[bufferlen];
// now can refer to buffer[0] ... buffer[bufferlen-1]
```

However, in C++, you should really use `std::vector` for arbitrary arrays, and you should use `std::string` for character arrays that are to be interpreted or used as strings.

There is no reason to invoke `::operator new` or `::operator new[]` explicitly rather than using the ordinary syntax for these calls. For POD and primitive types (e.g. `char`) no initialization will take place. If you need to get a `void*` buffer, then simply use `static_cast` to convert `char*` to `void*`.

Comment: The OP isn't talking about `new int` and `new int[5]`, but specifically calling the functions with the given names, e.g. `void* p = operator new(50);` vs `void* p = operator new[](50);`.

Comment: Your update is slightly wrong.  There's a difference between `new int` and `new int()` (the latter object is guaranteed to be initialized to zero), and similarly for any POD type.  One special case also works for new[]: `new int[5]()`.

Comment: @Roger, that is correct; however, in the syntax I gave, no initialization takes place.

Comment: That's why I said slightly, specifically: "For POD and primitive types (e.g. char) no initialization will take place."  You don't make it clear that `new int` is different semantics than `new int()`, but do characterize the whole "ordinary syntax".

Comment: Well, the suggestion to just use new char[] implies that I have to use ::operator new[].

Comment: @sharptooth: I believe he's saying you should use a new expression rather than calling operator new directly, not trying to imply anything about operator new vs operator new[].  However, you have considerably changed the question, because as written now you have no choice in how the third party library deallocates, rather than you having sole control yourself as you had before.

Comment: @Roger Pate: Yes, I completely understand his answer. Still I don't want to use the `new` statement simply to avoid casting from `char*` to `void*` and back even if `static_cast` will do the job at no cost. Anyway `new[]` statement implies `::operator new[]` and that more or less answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of the C++ `new` operators over C's `malloc()` and `free()` is that the former throws an exception if there is not enough memory, rather than returning `NULL`.

Regarding choosing new(size) and new[] for character buffers, I'd advocate the latter since it is less likely to surprise people maintaining the code later i.e. `char* buf = new char[size]` and `delete[] buf`.

The values in the buffer will not be initialised, and there is no range-checking - you have to build a nice C++ object to do that for you, or use an existing object such as `std::vector` or `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

The question cannot be answered sensibly.

Firstly, it is said that the program 'needs' a block of uninitialized memory but, from the code sample given, it seems that the program 'needs' a block of uninitialized and UNTYPED memory which seems not very C++ or OO.

Secondly, a std::vector gives sole and automatic control over a block of typed memory that may or may not change in size according to its use. You can lose this control if an instance of std::vector is created on the heap and tracked with raw pointers just as for any other C or C++ object such as a void* memory block.

Thirdly, what is the intended use of this memory block? The answer to this may or may not dictate the use of operator new or operator new[]. In the design of this program, is there a single interpretation of this memory block? What ownership semantics do you require, if any? Etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

for allocating memory to array/list use new[] other than that use new...