# why call operator new explicitly

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator

I saw code like this:

```
void *NewElts = operator new(NewCapacityInBytes);
```

And matching call explicitly `operator delete` is used consequent later.

Why do this instead of:

```
void *NewElts = new char[NewCapacityInBytes];
```

Why explicit call to `operator new` and `operator delete`??

Comment: You might find this related question interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2498183/57428

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Explicitly calling `operator new` like that calls the global "raw" operator new.  Global `operator new` returns a raw memory block without calling the object's constructor or any user-defined overloads of `new`.  So basically, global `operator new` is similar to `malloc` from C.

So:

```
// Allocates space for a T, and calls T's constructor,
// or calls a user-defined overload of new.
//
T* v = new T;

// Allocates space for N instances of T, and calls T's 
// constructor on each, or calls a user-defined overload
// of new[]
//
T* v = new T[N];

// Simply returns a raw byte array of `sizeof(T)` bytes.
// No constructor is invoked.
//
void* v = ::operator new(sizeof(T));
```

Comment: @zaharpopov: One example would be implementing a memory pool where you allocate a big chunk once and users of the pool would call functions that create objects within the chunk, instead of using `new`. Depending on the allocation pattern, this can provide better performance than `new` and `delete`.

Comment: Ooo. Interesting. I didn't know about *this* corner of C++.

Comment: This answer describes what `operator new` does, but it doesn't explain why we'd use `operator new(N)` instead of `new char[N]`. That was the question, after all.

Comment: I would say the difference is style. C++ gives you a lot of ways to do the same thing.

Comment: Actually, I should probably edit the answer to explicitly mention `new T[N]`.

Comment: I interpret this question as being specifically about `char`, where you're allocating an arbitrary block of bytes, rather than allocating a block to be the same size as some particular type `T`. Can you really overload `operator new` for `char`?

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: No, one can't overload `operator new` for a specific built-in type.

Answer (score 7):

If you write:

```
T *p = new T;
```

That allocates enough memory to hold a T, then constructs the T into it. If you write:

```
T *p = ::operator new(sizeof(T));
```

That allocates enough memory to hold a T, but doesn't construct the T. One of the times you might see this is when people are also using placement new:

```
T *p = ::operator new(sizeof(T)); // allocate memory for a T
new (p) T; // construct a T into the allocated memory
p->~T(); // destroy the T again
::operator delete(p); // deallocate the memory
```

Answer (score 2):

If you call operator new(bytesize), then you can delete it using delete, whereas if you allocate via new char[bytesize], then you have to match it using delete[], which is an abomination to be avoided wherever possible. This is most likely the root reason to use it.

Comment: If you allocate via global `operator new` you can deallocate it using global `operator delete`.  But global `operator delete` won't call the destructor.  So if you actually construct an object using placement new after calling global `operator new`, then global `operator delete` alone is not sufficient to destroy the object.  You need to also invoke the destructor explicitly before deallocating the memory.  Essentially, both global `operator new` and `operator delete` allow you to decouple storage allocation/deallocation and object initialization/destruction.

Comment: @Charles: He didn't placement new anything, and that memory doesn't need destructing. As a form of purely allocating memory, then operator new() is the safest bet because it doesn't need irritating delete[] or unusual free() to deallocate. @Steve: delete[] is an abomination because it's unnecessary. It's not like, when you use operator new and not new[], that the heap magically doesn't need to store the size of the block or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

Use it when you want to allocate a block of "raw" memory and don't want anything constructed in that memory.

There is little practical difference between allocating a block of raw memory and "constructing" an array of chars but using operator new clearly signals your intent to anyone reading the code which is important.